# Not found page is not coming up

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0

This is my site URL `http://www.leenewman.com/` and facing a problem with not found page this is not coming up at all even when I type a bogus URL like `http://www.leenewman.com/blahblah` it shows just home page rather than not found   page I have to check my admin for any given setting but no luck with that and google has no such result.

Anyone had solved this before please help this would really appreciable. 
`Note: Magento ver. 1.6.2.0`

Comment: I re-tagged your question since you say it's version `1.6.2.0`

Comment: Thanks Dan but any idea about the problem..

Comment: 'System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages -> CMS No Route Page' might be set as 'Homepage'. You have to set it to '404 Not Found'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the admin panel go to `System` > `Configuration` in the menu.

In the `Web` configuration, open the `Default Pages` tab.

Make sure that you select the correct CMS page (By default it's called `Page Not Found`) for the `CMS No Route Page` settings.

Comment: Default No-route URL is set to : cms/index/noRoute
And CMS No Route Page is set to 404 Not found