# All 'not found' pages routing to homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, 404-page

I have an issue that all pages that result in an error (such as 404) are routed to the site root despite the routing `config -> web -> default pages` being set to a 404 CMS page. I can't figure out what is happening.

I have checked:

- `magento rewrite table`
- `.htaccess for any rules`

I know this is vague, but any ideas on where to check configuration etc to determine what the routing issue is? There is a similar question that went unresolved according to final comment by poster here: [Not found page is not coming up](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/not-found-page-is-not-coming-up)

```
Running magento 1.9.3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check catalog->URL Rewrite Management-> choose type custom and see if you have any
ID Path *

Request Path *

301 redirect to ../ for home page

Comment: I don't have any such redirects. I still haven't figured it out.